# How can I use different form widgets in Django admin?

Tags: django, forms, widget

I tried with something like:

```
class PedidoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pedido
        widgets = {
            'nota': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

But it changes in both, list view and single object view. I'd like to change int only for the single object view. HOw can I do it?

I want this:

[image]

But not this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding widgets in the Meta class, just set the widget in an override of `__init__`, and specify the form in your admin class. The form you specify will only be used for the add/change views. Example:

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
class PedidoAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pedido

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PedidoAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['nota'].widget = forms.Textarea()

#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from your_app.forms import PedidoAdminForm
from your_app.models import Pedido

class PedidoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PedidoAdminForm
    list_editable = ['nota']
```

This works for me in Django 1.3. Hope that helps you out.